# Solr multiple facet.contains in query issue

Tags: solr, lucene

I have multiple `facet.contains` in solr query but it seems from result only first `facet.contains` is handled and others are discarded.

e.g. `facet.contains=w & facet.contains =t` result facets contains `w` and `t` in results is not always there.

Comment: not always? so, sometimes its working?

Comment: no it is never working.words which contains w may also have t in it,so I mentioned is "not always"

Comment: So, you have search results coming back that you don't want represented in facet results?  (It sounds like `facet.contains` accepts a single value).  Maybe you can constrain your query rather than your facets?

Comment: could you show full query example?

Comment: did you get the solution? I am facing the same issue.. I need to use multiple facet.contains in my query..

Answer (score -1):

facet.contains is global, you can only have one. You can have a different contains for different facets, but the facet specific version is f.myfacetfield.contains

[Solr 7.2 facet documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/faceting.html)